# Socket IO 400 Bad request on web-page

Tags: html, node.js, http, websocket, socket.io

*For Code check below*
I run the index.js, the html in index.html gets shows on example.com, but the client.js in index.html gives me the error:

```
GET http://example.com/socket.io/client.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Also, if I enter some text in the chat box and hit 'send', rather than printing the message on example.com, I get a blank **example.com/?**.

This is my index.js

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
// can now use `require` in an ESM

const app = require('express')();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = { /* ... */ };

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://example.com:80",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});


import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(80);
console.log("index.mjs running...");
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RAMBO</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my client.js

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
        const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
        // can now use `require` in an ESM
        
        
        require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
        module.exports = require("./main.js")
    
        const io = require("socket.io-client");
        const socket = io("http://api.example.com:80", {
          withCredentials: true,
          extraHeaders: {
            "my-custom-header": "abcd"
          }
        })
    
          var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
          var form = document.getElementById('form');
          var input = document.getElementById('input');

          form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value) {
              socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
              input.value = '';
            }
          });

          socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = msg;
            messages.appendChild(item);
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
          });
```

Comment: How do you serve `/socket.io/client.js`??

Comment: what do you mean? I thought it would work if I use it as a script outside the html file as client.js and referred to it in index.html with   <script src="/socket.io/client.js"></script> If it was outside socket.io I could not make the path work, it would always give me 404 not found.

Comment: Socket.io serves its own client file at /socket.io/socket.io.js nothing else(as far as i know) so when you want to use a js file you have written in a browser you need to serve it somehow. Usualy you do that by adding a middleware http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static then you place the file in a folder for example `<your app>/public/js/client.js` The middleware should serve the entire public folder `app.use(express.static('public'))` the you get the file at `/js/client.js`

Comment: thanks I will test that and post an update!